# How to determine if Windows Setup is complete programmatically

Tags: windows, powershell, installation

How can I check if the Windows setup process is complete from a script? I have a Powershell script that runs on new builds which sometimes gets kicked off before the Windows installation is complete, but needs to wait until setup is complete to execute.

Comment: How is the script being launched?

Comment: In our case, it gets kicked off from a vRO workflow. Problem is that the OS setup isn't completely done when the VM Customization is logged as completed.

Comment: If vRO doesn't provide a built-in solution, the safest approach would probably be to split it into two scripts, the first one could configure a startup task that runs the second one, or variants along that line.  Windows Setup isn't really complete until the system has rebooted.  (Well, that's true in an ordinary unattented installation, at any rate.)

Comment: What I ended up doing was poll for the processes until WinDeploy.exe was no longer running. Then I check that the system isn't rebooting. If the system is rebooting, I wait for the VM to come back up, and start checking again. So far though WinDeploy.exe is totally done after the reboot. And vRO *does* have a built in solution, but we aren't sure at this point why it continues on to the next step in the build process before it's finished (which makes me think it's a hard sleep somewhere in their code). Either way, the solution I came up with works rather well for us.

Comment: The reason we don't schedule the script as a task on the next boot is because if the script fails, we want to fail the VM request. If we hand the script off to Windows as a scheduled task, we lose insight as to whether or not the Windows' provisioning was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all processes and ensure that WinDeploy.exe is not among them. If WinDeploy.exe is running, then Windows' setup is not yet complete:

```
Get-Process -Name windeploy
```

Note that when WinDeploy.exe stops executing, you will need to ensure that the system is not rebooting before continuing, and wait until it comes back up before continuing execution. For our environment, it was easier to use the VMWare API from our deployment system to wait until WinDeploy.exe was finished executing and also check that the guest was in the `running` state before attempting to execute the provisioning script.

If this is something that you *have* to run in a local script for whatever reason, consider using Powershell workflows which can be used across reboots.

Comment: You could also just say `Get-Process -Name 'windeploy'`.  Might run a bit faster to not enumerate all processes in the pipeline.